# Configure log4j.properties file location when packing to jar

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have a concern that where do we have to put log4j.properties file when packaging to jar file by using maven.what is the best practice here.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traditional Open Source Java Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056080/traditional-open-source-java-application)

Comment: Make sure you read the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056230/289086) to that suggested duplicate and follow the link to [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: The answer to the question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897528/problems-to-put-log4-properties-classpath)

Answer (score 1):

**General recommendation**

Put it into `src/main/resources`. You may want to define a more verbose log4j configuration in `src/test/resources`, if you do use junit tests.

See [maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

**Setting a new configuration for specific executions**

If you want to create an executable jar with a main method, you can ship a default configuration in `src/main/resources` and still provide an overriding log configuration when starting your jvm, using this jvm parameter: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:"<FILE_PATH>"`.

**Building for multiple environments**

You can also create multiple subfolders in your resource configuration and have the maven resource plugin copy the correct log4j.xml to the destination via [maven profiles](http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/docs/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering).